# Azure Web Jobs: Logs are not working even after setting App Service Logs settings

Tags: azure, logging, azure-webjobs, azure-webjobs-continuous

I've a continuous Azure Web Job running. However, after a few lines of log it throws following warning and stops logging.

`[WARN] Reached maximum allowed output lines for this run, to see all of the job's logs you can enable App Service Logs option in the Portal.`

I've **changed the configs at App Service logs** as per the attached screenshot and restarted the job, with no success.

[image]

Comment: You can check the web job logs in `WebJobs` => `Logs` section.[Image](https://i.imgur.com/lh6kQRO.png)

Comment: In App Service logs, Change the log level to Information and check once.

Comment: Thanks Harshita. WebJobs => Logs section is the one that gives warning as reached maximum allowed output lines. Changing the log level did not help either :(

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to resolve it with FileSystem storage. However, Blob storage helped here and I was able to find the logs in my storage account.